# Как это ускорить (почему это так медленно работает)?

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js, математика, скорость

Немного о задаче:
У меня есть функция (js), которая принимает аргумент и возвращает вычисленное по математической формуле значение

```
var f = function(x) {
    return 3*Math.sin(2*x)*Math.pow(Math.cos(x), 4);
}
```

Также у меня есть массив, индекс - номер интервала (индексация с нуля), значение элемента по индексу - кол-во раз, когда значение попадало в этот индекс.

Например, если у меня в массиве 2 элемента, и значения которые меня интересуют от 0 до 1, то если f(x) вернуло число, меньшее 0,5, то первый элемент массива увеличиться на 1, если большее 0,5, то второй элемент соответственно увеличится на 1.

Я модифицировал функцию, чтобы она сразу возвращала, тот номер интервала, в который попадёт значение при данном  аргументе.

```
var hist_min = 0;
var hist_max = 2;
var hist_range = hist_max-hist_min;
var hist_cols = 30;

var f = function(x) {
    return  Math.floor(((3*Math.sin(2*x)*Math.pow(Math.cos(x), 4)-hist_min)/hist_range) * hist_cols);
}
```

В приведённом выше примере у меня 30 интервалов, левая граница самого левого - 0, правая правого - 2.

Далее я замеряю скорость выполнения 3*10^6 итераций  этой функции.

```
var iteratitions = 3000000;

var start_time = Date.now();
for (var i=0; i < iteratitions; i++) {
    var need_col = f(Math.random())
}
console.log("Finished in",Date.now()-start_time+"ms")
```

получается довольно быстро, на моём компьютере ~100-200ms

Однако, мне нужно как-то сохранять эти интервалы, например в массив.

Я делаю так

```
var start_time = Date.now();

for (var i=0; i < iteratitions; i++) {
    var need_col = f(Math.random())
    arr[need_col]++;
}

console.log("Finished in",Date.now()-start_time+"ms")
```

Однако так уже выполняется значительно дольше ~1300ms

Сначала я думал, это из-за того, что `arr[need_col]++` сильно долго выполняется, однако если сделать так:

```
for (var i=0; i < iteratitions; i++) {
    var need_col = f(Math.random())
    var need_col2 = 3
    arr[need_col2]++;
}
```

И это выполняется уже за ~130ms

Возникает вопрос, почему если я просто сохраняю значение функции f в переменную need_col, всё работает быстро, а как только я использую переменную need_col (передаю как индекс), то всё замедляется в разы?

Привожу весь код

```js
var hist_min = 0;
var hist_max = 2;
var hist_range = hist_max-hist_min;
var hist_cols = 30;

var need_col = 0;

/*
var f = function(x) {
 return 3*Math.sin(2*x)*Math.pow(Math.cos(x), 4)
}
*/

var f = function(x) {
 return  Math.floor(((3*Math.sin(2*x)*Math.pow(Math.cos(x), 4)-hist_min)/hist_range) * hist_cols);
}

var iteratitions = 3000000;
var arr = [];

// инициализация
for (var i=0; i < hist_cols; i++) {
 arr.push(0)
}

// пустой цикл занимает время
var start_time = Date.now();

for (var i=0; i < iteratitions; i++) {
}
console.log("empty loop finished in",Date.now()-start_time+"ms")


// просто увеличение элемента массива по индексу
var start_time = Date.now();

for (var i=0; i < iteratitions; i++) {
 var need_col = 3
 arr[need_col]++;
}
console.log("arr[need_col]++; Finished in",Date.now()-start_time+"ms")


// просто выполение f(x) 
var start_time = Date.now();

for (var i=0; i < iteratitions; i++) {
 need_col = f(Math.random())
 //var need_col2 = 3
 //arr[need_col2]++;
}
console.log("just f(x) finished in",Date.now()-start_time+"ms")
//console.log(need_col)

// заполнение массива тем, что нам нужно
var start_time = Date.now();

for (var i=0; i < iteratitions; i++) {
 var need_col = f(Math.random())
 arr[need_col]++;
}
console.log("filling array f(x) finished in",Date.now()-start_time+"ms")

console.log("arr=", arr)
```

P.S. на моём компьютере немного другие цифры (я выполняю код через node)
[image: вывод консоли]

Comment: Скорее всего просто движок понимает, что вы нигде не используете `need_col` и вообще ее не считает. Так что вы замеряете просто пустые итерации цикла.

Comment: Да, но в таком случае если я уберу тело из цикла, то время выполнения будет тем же. Но когда я убрал тело цикла, то пустые итерации цикла прошлись за 15-20ms

Comment: Можете попробовать сначала инициализировать массив  нужного размера пустыми значениями. Должно быть чуточку быстрее. Во втором случае действительно, `var need_col = f(Math.random())` просто не выполняется.

Comment: я не указал здесь, но инициализацию я провожу: `arr` содержит 30 нулей. По поводу того, что `var need_col = f(Math.random())` не выполняется. Дело в том, что когда я закомментировал эту строку, цикл стал значительно быстрее работать (~25ms). Я попробую сделать возможность выполнить код прямо здесь

Comment: После `console.log("just f(x) finished in", Date.now() - start_time + "ms")` напишите `console.log(need_col)`. И результат изменится

Comment: Да, действительно изменилось... Т.е. выходит, что это никак ускорить нельзя?

Comment: А вы пробовали смотреть что в результе в массиве? У вас явно где-то ошибка в вычислениях потому что массив получается сильно больше 30 элементов

Comment: Ваша функция на отрезке от 0 до 1 имеет максимум чуть больше 1.55, а судя по вашей формуле вы ожидаете что значения у неё от 0 до 1. https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/xmdwfxnk

Comment: Выводит NaN там, где больше 1

Comment: Я планировал проверку поставить

Comment: Собственно тормозит из-за выхода за границы массива. Движку приходится увеличивать массив. А ещё потом вместо простого сложения заниматься сложением `undefined + 1` (что довольно дорого) и получать NaN

Comment: но я наверное сейчас просто `hist_max` больше сделаю. Сделал

Comment: А `hist_max` у вас в коде вообще не используется

Comment: неплохо, вышло ускорение почти в 2 раза! Но никак нельзя это ускорить сильнее? (Меня очень смущает, что если просто в цикле выполнять `f(Math.random())` выполняется так быстро). Может есть какие-то более оптимальные структуры в js, которые будут быстрее изменять (увеличивать) значение элементов?

Comment: А вы посмотрите не просто `f(...)`, а например `s+=f(...)`. Кажется движок просто оптимизирует вызовы у которых результат не используется

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107998/discussion-between---and-alexey-ten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном конкретном вопросе проблема в том, что функция `3*Math.sin(2*x)*Math.pow(Math.cos(x), 4)` на отрезке `[0, 1)` имеет значения о `0` до примерно `1.553`, но функция пересчёта в номер интервала (до изменения вопроса) была рассчитана на значения от `0` до `1`. Поэтому для значений больше `1` вызов `arr[need_col]++` выходил за границы массива и это приводило к сильному замедлению (и значениям `NaN` в массиве).

Сравнение `for(..) { f(x); }` и `for(..) { arr[f(x)]++; }` некорректно. В первом случае движок понимает, что результат вызова функции не используется и экономит на возврате значения. А если заметит, что это вообще чистая функция, то в теории может её вообще не вызывать.

Корректнее сравнивать с (например) `s = 0; for(..) { s += f(x) }`, и тут результат не сильно отличается от доступа к массиву.

Таким образом можно считать, что всё что можно было сделать в рамках JS уже сделано. Если нужно быстрее, то надо смотреть в сторону других ЯП, но это выходит за рамки данного вопроса.

Answer (score -2):

Индекс это строка, разница во времени посути в need_col.toString() внутри гетера массива.

```
new Proxy ([ 1 ],{
    get : function ( target , key ){
        console . log ( target , typeof key , key );
        // [ 1 ] string 0
    }
})[ 0 ] ++ ;
```

Comment: А есть в javascript такие структуры данных, которые не преобразуют индекс в строку?

Comment: new Map(), но быстрей работать не будет